# Launching Script/Executable from SFX archive on Linux

Tags: linux, centos, self-extracting

I want to create a SFX installer on linux. I got source for p7Zip from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/files/) and able to build it in linux. Now I want to create SFX style archive which will launch some script or executable upon extracting on linux, any idea how to achive this in p7zip? also How do I tell the sfx archive to install to specific directory (e.g. /usr/temp)

Comment: AFAIK the sfx is Windows only.  what led you to believe that this worked on Linux?

Comment: I don't think so. sfx is way of archiving the things in addition to that it provide feature to launch some custom script or programs upon extraction.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the tool called [makeself](http://megastep.org/makeself/).

[makeself.sh](http://megastep.org/makeself/makeself.run) is a small shell script that generates a self-extractable tar.gz archive from a directory. The resulting file appears as a shell script (many of those have a .run suffix), and can be launched as is. The archive will then uncompress itself to a temporary directory and an optional arbitrary command will be executed

Comment: While this may solve your problem, it isn't a good answer in the context of this site since it is link-only answer.  Please add at least a brief summary.  Your link is broken when I try to visit it, which makes it a worthless answer if anyone else found this question in a search result.

Comment: Please don't provide link-only answers on Superuser, linked pages move or get deleted. Add an abridged version or description in your answer so future visitors can make sense of your answer. N.B. I'd edit your answer myself but the link you have provided is, currently, refusing to load.